# SQL smalldatetime SELECT query

Tags: sql

I need to select rows from table, where `smalldatetime` between two values.

Im trying do that query, but it's dont work:

```
SELECT [numdoc]
  ,[numdok]
  ,[kodsotr]
  ,[dateShip]
  ,[pallCount]
 FROM [tsdgreen].[dbo].[ShipmentControl]
 WHERE [dateShip] > '2015/12/10 10:58:00' 
AND [dateShip] < '2015/12/11 10:42:00'
```

Comment: could you post the result of 

" select * from ...  limit 1 ;" 

that would help debug

Comment: Which DBMS is this? Also, show some sample data, desired output and actual output. Also, error message if any.

Comment: Always use date and time format while comparing these columns.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of DateTime where the year is in front is sometimes confusing.
Your Date and Month fields are likely backwards.
By default it is expects **`YYYY/DD/MM`** and NOT **`YYYY/MM/DD`**

In Oracle you may also use the explicit format conversion: **`TO_DATE('2015/12/10','yyyy/mm/dd')`** to ensure the date is in the same format your sending.

Also, if using Microsoft SQL, then you should use the `BETWEEN` keyword as this example demonstrates:

```
SELECT 
    [numdoc]
    ,[numdok]
    ,[kodsotr]
    ,[dateShip]
    ,[pallCount]
FROM 
    [tsdgreen].[dbo].[ShipmentControl]
WHERE 
    [dateShip] BETWEEN '2015/10/12 10:58:00' AND '2015/11/12 10:42:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

In OracleSQL you can write like :

```
SELECT [numdoc]
  ,[numdok]
  ,[kodsotr]
  ,[dateShip]
  ,[pallCount]
 FROM [tsdgreen].[dbo].[ShipmentControl]
 WHERE [dateShip] > TO_DATE('2015/12/10','yyyy/mm/dd') 
AND [dateShip] < TO_DATE('2015/12/11','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
2015/12/10 10:58:00 means YYYY/DD/MM, i think that was YYYY/MM/DD